# Time distributed cnn + lstm does not allow more that one sample in batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have modified the inceptionV3 model to accept timeframes using time distributed layers. The model looks like this:

```
def inception():
init_training_mode()
network = input_data(shape=[None, 5, 150, 200, 1], dtype=float32, name='input')
conv1_7_7 = time_distributed(network, conv_2d, [64, 7, 2, "same", "relu"])
pool1_3_3 = time_distributed(conv1_7_7, max_pool_2d, [3, 2])
pool1_3_3 = time_distributed(pool1_3_3, local_response_normalization)
conv2_3_3_reduce = time_distributed( pool1_3_3, conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, "same", 'relu'])
conv2_3_3 = time_distributed(conv2_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [192, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
conv2_3_3 = time_distributed(conv2_3_3, local_response_normalization)
pool2_3_3 = time_distributed(conv2_3_3, max_pool_2d, [3, 2])

# 3a
inception_3a_1_1 = time_distributed(pool2_3_3, conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_3a_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(pool2_3_3, conv_2d, [96, 1, 1,'same', 'relu'])
inception_3a_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_3a_3_3_reduce,conv_2d, [128, 3, 1,  'same', 'relu'])
inception_3a_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(pool2_3_3, conv_2d, [16, 1, 1, 'same','relu'])
inception_3a_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_3a_5_5_reduce,conv_2d, [32, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_3a_pool = time_distributed(pool2_3_3, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_3a_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_3a_pool, conv_2d, [32, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_3a_output = merge([inception_3a_1_1, inception_3a_3_3, inception_3a_5_5, inception_3a_pool_1_1], mode='concat', axis=4)

# 3b
inception_3b_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_3a_output,conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_3b_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(inception_3a_output,conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same','relu'])
inception_3b_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_3b_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [192, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_3b_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(inception_3a_output,conv_2d, [32, 1, 1,  'same', 'relu'])
inception_3b_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_3b_5_5_reduce,conv_2d, [96, 5, 1])
inception_3b_pool = time_distributed(inception_3a_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_3b_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_3b_pool, conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_3b_output = merge([inception_3b_1_1, inception_3b_3_3, inception_3b_5_5, inception_3b_pool_1_1], mode='concat', axis=4, name='inception_3b_output')
pool3_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_3b_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 2])

# 4a
inception_4a_1_1 = time_distributed(pool3_3_3, conv_2d,[192, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4a_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(pool3_3_3,conv_2d,[ 96, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4a_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_4a_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [208, 3,  1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4a_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(pool3_3_3,conv_2d,[ 16, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4a_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_4a_5_5_reduce, conv_2d, [48, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4a_pool = time_distributed(pool3_3_3, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_4a_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4a_pool,conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4a_output = merge([inception_4a_1_1, inception_4a_3_3, inception_4a_5_5, inception_4a_pool_1_1], mode='concat', axis=4, name='inception_4a_output')

# 4b
inception_4b_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4a_output, conv_2d, [160, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4b_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4a_output,conv_2d, [112, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4b_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_4b_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [ 224, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4b_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4a_output, conv_2d, [ 24, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4b_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_4b_5_5_reduce,conv_2d, [ 64, 5,  1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4b_pool = time_distributed(inception_4a_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_4b_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4b_pool,conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4b_output = merge([inception_4b_1_1, inception_4b_3_3, inception_4b_5_5, inception_4b_pool_1_1], mode='concat', axis=4, name='inception_4b_output')

# 4c
inception_4c_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4b_output, conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4c_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4b_output, conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4c_3_3 =  time_distributed(inception_4c_3_3_reduce,  conv_2d, [256, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4c_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4b_output, conv_2d, [24, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4c_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_4c_5_5_reduce, conv_2d, [64, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4c_pool = time_distributed(inception_4b_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_4c_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4c_pool, conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4c_output = merge([inception_4c_1_1, inception_4c_3_3, inception_4c_5_5, inception_4c_pool_1_1], mode='concat', axis=4, name='inception_4c_output')

# 4d
inception_4d_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4c_output, conv_2d, [112, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4d_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4c_output,  conv_2d, [114, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4d_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_4d_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [228, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4d_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4c_output, conv_2d, [32, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4d_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_4d_5_5_reduce,conv_2d, [64, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4d_pool = time_distributed(inception_4c_output, max_pool_2d,[3, 1])
inception_4d_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4d_pool, conv_2d, [64, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4d_output = merge([inception_4d_1_1, inception_4d_3_3, inception_4d_5_5, inception_4d_pool_1_1], mode='concat', axis=4, name='inception_4d_output')

# 4e
inception_4e_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4d_output, conv_2d, [256, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4e_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4d_output, conv_2d, [160, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4e_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_4e_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [320, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4e_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(inception_4d_output, conv_2d, [32, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4e_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_4e_5_5_reduce, conv_2d, [128, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4e_pool = time_distributed(inception_4d_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_4e_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_4e_pool, conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_4e_output = merge([inception_4e_1_1, inception_4e_3_3, inception_4e_5_5, inception_4e_pool_1_1], axis=4, mode='concat')
pool4_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_4e_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 2])

# 5a
inception_5a_1_1 = time_distributed(pool4_3_3, conv_2d, [256, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5a_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(pool4_3_3, conv_2d, [160, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5a_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_5a_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [320, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5a_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(pool4_3_3, conv_2d, [32, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5a_5_5 = time_distributed(inception_5a_5_5_reduce, conv_2d, [128, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5a_pool = time_distributed(pool4_3_3, max_pool_2d,[3, 1])
inception_5a_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_5a_pool, conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5a_output = merge([inception_5a_1_1, inception_5a_3_3, inception_5a_5_5, inception_5a_pool_1_1], axis=4, mode='concat')

# 5b
inception_5b_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_5a_output,  conv_2d, [384, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5b_3_3_reduce = time_distributed(inception_5a_output, conv_2d, [192, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5b_3_3 = time_distributed(inception_5b_3_3_reduce, conv_2d, [384, 3, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5b_5_5_reduce = time_distributed(inception_5a_output, conv_2d, [48, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5b_5_5 =  time_distributed(inception_5b_5_5_reduce, conv_2d, [128, 5, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5b_pool = time_distributed(inception_5a_output, max_pool_2d, [3, 1])
inception_5b_pool_1_1 = time_distributed(inception_5b_pool,  conv_2d, [128, 1, 1, 'same', 'relu'])
inception_5b_output = merge([inception_5b_1_1, inception_5b_3_3, inception_5b_5_5, inception_5b_pool_1_1], axis=4, mode='concat')
pool5_7_7 = time_distributed(inception_5b_output, avg_pool_2d, [7, 1])
pool5_7_7 = time_distributed(pool5_7_7, dropout, [0.4])

#lstm
reshaped =reshape(pool5_7_7, [-1, 5, 1024])
#reshaped = time_distributed(pool5_7_7, reshape, [[-1, 1024], 'reshape'])

from tflearn import lstm
lstm1 = lstm(reshaped, 1024, return_seq=True, activation = 'tanh')
lstm1 = dropout(lstm1, 0.8)
lstm2 = lstm(lstm1, 512, return_seq=True, activation = 'tanh')
lstm2 = dropout(lstm2, 0.8)
lstm3 = lstm(lstm2, 256, activation = 'tanh')
lstm3 = dropout(lstm3, 0.8)

loss = fully_connected(lstm3, 20, activation='softmax')
network = regression(loss, optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.001,
                     name = 'targets')

model = DNN(network,
                    checkpoint_path='G:\\LogDirs\\Brawlhalla\\Checkpoints\\googlenet',
                    best_checkpoint_path='G:\\LogDirs\\Brawlhalla\\Checkpoints\\googlenet_best',
                    max_checkpoints=2,
                    best_val_accuracy=0.2,
                    tensorboard_verbose=1,
                    tensorboard_dir='G:\\LogDirs\\tensorboard\\BrLstm')
return model
```

For the training data, I've captured some gameframes, processed them into (200, 150, 1) grayscale images and packed them into 5 frames window. I've checked the shape (5000, 5, 150, 200, 1) and the quality of the training data. The problem is that i cannot increase the batchsize because of the error:

```
    2018-08-28 11:57:38.113766: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\bfc_allocator.cc:219] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 712.36MiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [175] vs. [5]
     [[Node: Accuracy/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Accuracy/ArgMax, Accuracy/ArgMax_1)]]
     [[Node: ConstantFolding/Adam/gradients/Conv2D_62/Conv2D_grad/ShapeN-matshapes-1/_1375 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_18098...atshapes-1", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/FastPy/Brawlhalla/CreateLstmData.py", line 157, in <module>
    run_id='LstmCeption')
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\models\dnn.py", line 216, in fit
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 339, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\helpers\trainer.py", line 818, in _train
    feed_batch)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [175] vs. [5]
     [[Node: Accuracy/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Accuracy/ArgMax, Accuracy/ArgMax_1)]]
     [[Node: ConstantFolding/Adam/gradients/Conv2D_62/Conv2D_grad/ShapeN-matshapes-1/_1375 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_18098...atshapes-1", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Accuracy/Equal', defined at:
  File "C:/FastPy/Brawlhalla/CreateLstmData.py", line 147, in <module>
    model = inception()
  File "C:\FastPy\Brawlhalla\Inception.py", line 147, in inception
    name = 'targets')
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\layers\estimator.py", line 156, in regression
    metric.build(incoming, placeholder, inputs)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\metrics.py", line 104, in build
    self.tensor = accuracy_op(predictions, targets)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tflearn\metrics.py", line 267, in accuracy_op
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(targets, 1))
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 2862, in equal
    "Equal", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "G:\Programe\Conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [175] vs. [5]
     [[Node: Accuracy/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Accuracy/ArgMax, Accuracy/ArgMax_1)]]
     [[Node: ConstantFolding/Adam/gradients/Conv2D_62/Conv2D_grad/ShapeN-matshapes-1/_1375 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_18098...atshapes-1", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

If I train my network with only one sample per batch, it doesn't converge even after 3 days, no matter what lr I use, so I think that the problem is not the batchsize, but something else in the model.